# Efficient way to look up sequential values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Each 'Product' can have as many as 10000 'Segment' rows. The segments have a sort column that starts at 1 for each product (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...) and a value column that can contain any values such as (323.113, 5423.231, 873.42, 422.64, 763.1, ...).

I would like to identify potential matches for products given a subset of segments. For example, if I have 5 segment values in the correct order, how can I efficiently find all the products which have all 5 segments in the same order somewhere in the Segment table?

---

**Update**

I posted a follow-up question to this here: [Find a series of data using non-exact measurements (fuzzy logic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042327/find-a-series-of-data-using-non-exact-measurements-fuzzy-logic)

Comment: by "in the same order" you mean with the same sort column value, correct? Could you spell out your schema a little better?

Comment: I should also mention that if the database schema needs to be tweaked to make this work or to make it work faster - that's definitely a possibility.

Comment: No, the sort column value is unknown. One product may have the subset of values early on in the sequence, another may have it later on. Another may have the subset occurring multiple times.

Comment: Think of the product as a song and the segments as a set of notes in the song. Given a set of notes, which can appear multiple times in a song and in multiple songs, what are the matching songs?

Comment: Is you collection of segments for a product static or can it change over time? Is space an issue for your algorithm or can you use more space to get less time?

Comment: Static. Once the segments are in the database they don't change.

Comment: Space may become an issue. I'm not sure yet. I'll have to evaluate which method works best once I get a better idea of how much data I will be dealing with.

Comment: So segment values in the same order and contiguous? or just in the same order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume tables like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
 (
   ProductId  int           not null
    constraint PK_Products
     primary key
  ,Name       varchar(100)  not null
 )

CREATE TABLE Segments
 (
   ProductId   int    not null
    constraint FK_Segments__Products
     foreign key references Products (ProductId)
  ,OrderBy     int    not null
  ,Value       float  not null
  ,constraint PK_Segments
    primary key (ProductId, OrderBy)
 )
```

Next, set up your search data in a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE #MatchThis
 (
   Position  int    not null
  ,Value     float  not null
 )
```

For N search objects, this has to be populated like so

```
First item   0    <value 1>
Second item  1    <value 2>
Third item   2    <value 3>
...
Nth item     N-1  <value N>
```

Now set up some important values. (This could be crammed into the final query, but this way makes it easier to read, and may improve performance slightly.)

```
DECLARE
  @ItemCount   int
 ,@FirstValue  float

--  How many items to be matched ("N", above)
SELECT @ItemCount = count(*)
 from #MatchThis

--  The value of the first item in the search set
SELECT @FirstValue = Value
 from #MatchThis
 where Position = 0
```

And then it's just a query:

```
SELECT
   pr.Name
  ,fv.OrderBy  --  Required by the Group By, but otherwise can be ignored
 from #MatchThis mt
  cross join (--  All Segments that match the first value in the set
              select ProductId, OrderBy
               from Segment
               where Value = @FirstValue) fv
  inner join Product pr  --  Just to get the Product name
   on pr.ProductId = fv.ProductId
  inner join Segment se
   on se.ProductId = fv.ProductId
    and se.OrderBy = fv.OrderBy + mt.Position  --  Lines them up based on the first value
    and se.Value = mt.Value                    --  No join if the values don't match
 group by
   pr.Name
  ,fv.OrderBy
 having count(*) = @ItemCount  --  Only include if as many segments pulled for this product/segment.OrderBy as are required
```

I am convinced this will work, but I don't have time to test it out in detail just now. To optimize for performance, besides the primary keys indicated you could add a regular index on Segment.Value

Comment: +1 If `OrderBy` doesn't contain gaps then this should work quite well I think.

Comment: True, I did make that assumption... but it is implied by the description of the data.

Comment: Yep agreed, sounds like it should be something within the OP's power to ensure.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly what I am trying to suggest takes too much space: once you add a new product, since the segments are static, you may index them by taking all the "suffixes" of the segment list.

For example, the segments list:

```
34 57 67 34
```

will produce:

```
34 57 67 34
57 67 34
67 34
34
```

You may need to store them in hard drive files, because for 10000 segments for each product, you will get a lot of "suffixes" (up to 10000 per product actually). The good news is that you can store them contiguously so you don't have too many hard disk seeks.
Then, you can simply linearly scan the suffix list and match the first k values for a query that contains k segment values. So, if in the above list you are searching for 57 67, it will return that product, because it matches the second suffix.

You can also do a tree indexing for faster matching, but this can get too complicated.

Edit: As I was saying in the comment, this is an adaptation of substring matching. You must also sort the suffixes number by number, and then you can do binary search over the list of suffixes, which in theory should indicate a match/mismatch in log(10000) steps.

Comment: 'Too complicated' is not something that I'm worried about. This has to happen one way or another. I hadn't thought of doing this outside of a database. If I were to re-ask this question so it wasn't SQL Server specific, what are some tags I could include to get the right people to answer with more solutions like this? I don't know the terminology for these kind of algorithms.

Comment: This algorithm is in fact used for substring matching in text search.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best performing way of doing this would be to store a denormalized version of the data.

```
ProductId, DelimitedList
1          ,323.113,5423.231,873.42,422.64,763.1,
```

Then your search is a simple

```
WHERE DelimitedList LIKE '%,323.113,5423.231,873.42,%'
```

You could do a standard relational division query first to bring back those `ProductId` values that match all values (not necessarily in the correct order or contiguous) to reduce the number of strings that are searched.

### Full Demo Script

```
/*Set up test tables*/
CREATE TABLE Products(
ProductId int primary key)


CREATE TABLE ProductSegments(
ProductId int REFERENCES Products,
Sort int,
Value decimal(10,3)
Primary key (ProductId,Sort))

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON ProductSegments(ProductId,Value)


CREATE TABLE ProductSegmentsDenormalized
(
ProductId int REFERENCES Products,
DelimitedList varchar(max)
)

/*Insert some initial data to Products...*/
INSERT INTO Products VALUES (1),(2),(3)

/*... and for ProductSegments*/
;WITH numbers(N)
     AS (SELECT TOP 10000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
         FROM   master..spt_values v1,
                master..spt_values v2)
INSERT INTO ProductSegments
            (ProductId,
             Sort,
             Value)
SELECT ProductId AS Product,
       n1.N      Sort,
       ( ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))% 1000000000 ) / 1000.00
FROM   numbers n1,
       Products  



/*Set up table for search data*/

DECLARE @SearchValues TABLE
(
Sequence int primary key,
Value decimal(10,3)
)
INSERT INTO @SearchValues
VALUES (1,323.113),(2,5423.231),(3,873.420),(4,422.640),(5,763.100)



/*Fiddle the test data so we have some guaranteed matches*/
UPDATE ps 
SET ps.Value = sv.Value
FROM ProductSegments ps
JOIN @SearchValues sv ON ProductId = 1 AND Sort = 100 + Sequence

UPDATE ps 
SET ps.Value = sv.Value
FROM ProductSegments ps
JOIN @SearchValues sv ON ProductId = 3 AND Sort = 987 + Sequence


/*Create the denormalised data*/
INSERT INTO ProductSegmentsDenormalized
SELECT ProductId, '|' + DelimitedList
FROM Products p
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT CAST(Value as varchar) + '|'
                 FROM ProductSegments ps
                 WHERE ps.ProductId = p.ProductId
                 ORDER BY Sort
                 FOR XML PATH('') )  D ( DelimitedList )
                 


/*Do the search*/
SELECT ProductId
FROM   ProductSegmentsDenormalized psd
WHERE  psd.ProductId IN (SELECT p.ProductId
                         FROM   Products p
                         WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                            FROM   @SearchValues sv
                                            WHERE  NOT EXISTS
                                                   (SELECT *
                                                    FROM ProductSegments ps
                                                    WHERE ps.ProductId = p.ProductId
                                                    AND sv.Value = ps.Value)))
AND DelimitedList LIKE '%|' + (SELECT CAST(Value AS VARCHAR) + '|'
                                FROM   @SearchValues sv
                                ORDER  BY Sequence
                                FOR XML PATH('')) + '%'
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea.  Even if the ordering is correct, the delimited list may have an extra element that he isn't searching on and this data structure would break down.  More over, if the ordering of the stored data isn't enforced, he would still get misses unless the storage ordering matches the search string ordering.

Comment: @Strommy - Quite self evidently the delimited list needs to be generated in the correct order for this scheme to work (easily done using the "normal" `XML PATH` approach to simulating `group_concat`). I don't really see your point. The extra element bit is irrelevant as the OP clarifies they are looking for **contiguous** segments. (Even if they weren't this could be easily adjusted for with additional wild cards)

Comment: Agreed on the ordering bit.  Clarified in later comments.  Also agreed on contiguous.  My beef with your solution is that the schema change you are proposing provides questionable local optimization, while providing a sub-optimal global solution.  Can you clarify how this will be a performant solution?

Comment: @M S: I suppose that's true when you approach a significant list of ordered elements, but would you want to have to edit that column?  Also, searching for all products with 1 segment forces a table scan.  Each solution has a trade-off, but THe devil is in the detail.  I guess more info is needed, correct?

Comment: @Strommy - The OP also clarifies in the comments that the segments are static so the creation of each list is a one time deal.

Comment: Agreed.  My bad.  Not on my A game today.  Missed important details.